# cutting webm with ffmpeg not producing output

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to cut a webm without encoding because I lose transparency when I encode it. But when i use a start time that's anything but 00:00:00 it doesn't produce an output. It simply says "Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)"

I can cut from the end but not from the beginning.

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:00:44 output.webm
```

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 0):

Okay well I wasn't able to find an exact fix but I was able to encode with transparency using "-c:v libvpx-vp9." My final code was:

> ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm -ss 30 -t 45 out.webm